# Deprecate method but keep functionality

Tags: java, deprecated

Say I have a library with an abstract class which has an abstract method:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass{

    public void myMethod(){
        int a = doSomething("hi");
    }

    public abstract void doSomething(String param);
}
```

Now I've decided to add a parameter to the method, but I want to keep the functionality of the old method to keep old code usable:

```
public void myMethod(){
    int a = ?
}

/**
 * @deprecated use doSomething(String, String) instead.
 */
@Deprecated
public int doSomething(String param){ return doSomething(param, null); }

public abstract int doSomething(String param, String secondParam);
```

How would I implement my `myMethod` in this scenario?

---

The [`PagerAdapter`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.2_r1/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.java#PagerAdapter.startUpdate%28android.view.View%29) class in the Android support library has in fact some kind of construction like this, but the other way around:

```
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    return instantiateItem((View) container, position);
}

/**
 * @deprecated Use {@link #instantiateItem(ViewGroup, int)}
 */
public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
            "Required method instantiateItem was not overridden");
}
```

Should this behavior be discouraged? And if I were to use this construction, how would I know what method to call?

Comment: How could the old code be usable? You introduced a new abstract method, breaking all the existing subclasses.

Comment: Why can't you keep calling `doSomething("hi")` (with a suppression warning) or just call `doSomething("hi", null)`?

Comment: You can call the new `doSomething(String, String)` in `myMethod()`.

Comment: @JBNizet Hmm, true. So the best way is to remove the `abstract` keyword and throw some error saying that the method needs to be overridden?

Comment: @JonSkeet I want to add some extra data for the implementer to (optionally) use to calculate the result.

Comment: That would still be broken, but without compilation error (which is worse). I would leave it as an abstract method, and refactor all the subclasses. And then do what Jon Skeet suggests.

Comment: @JB Nizet - If it is a library used by third parties, he may not have access to subclasses.

Comment: @JBNizet Well if I would know if `doSomething(String)` were overridden I could call that method, otherwise I would call `doSomething(String, String)`, possibly throwing that Exception if that isn't overridden either.

Comment: @JBNizet Plus what theon says, exactly.

Comment: If there are subclasses that you can't modify, then adding a new abstract method will cause exceptions every time this new method is called on a subclass instance. What would you like to do when the 2-arg method doesn't exist? Call the 1-arg method instead (and thus ignoring the second arg), or throw an exception?

Comment: Then the second argument could indeed be ignored (the second argument is IRL added to provide an option to get better performance).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I see your predicament. You have an abstract class in a library that people are subclassing and implementing it's abstract method and you want deprecate this method and add a new abstract method that moving forward should be implemented instead.

Here's what I would do:

## Before

Starting with a `Feature` class that users of your library are subclassing

```
public abstract class Feature {
    public abstract void doSomething(String param);
}
```

## After

Keep the `Feature` class pretty much as it is, however deprecate the method and advertise in your documentation that people should now subclass `NewFeature` instead of `Feature` and implement the shiny new abstract method in that class. Existing code that subclasses `Feature` should still work.

```
public abstract class Feature {
    /**
      @deprecated Extend NewFeature instead and implement doSomething(a, b) 
    */
    @Deprecated
    public abstract void doSomething(String param);
}

public abstract class NewFeature extends Feature {

    @Deprecated
    @Override
    public void doSomething(String param) {
        doSomething(param, null);
    }

    public abstract void doSomething(String param, String paramTwo);
}
```

## Further in the future

Once enough time has passed you could remove the `Feature` class. For example, I think spring tend to remove methods one whole version after they were first advertised as deprecated.

Comment: This looks indeed as the ideal way to go. I could check if the class is a subclass of `NewFeature` to decide what method to call. As a matter of fact, I wouldn't need to call `doSomething(param, null)` in the `doSomething()` method of `NewFeature` as it will never be called anyway?

Comment: Yeah sure - whatever makes sense really. It's hard to say without a concrete example.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, here's what I would do instead:

```
public void myMethod(){
    int a = doSomething("hi", "theOptimalSecondArgumentValue");
}

/**
 * @deprecated use doSomething(String, String) instead.
 */
@Deprecated
public abstract int doSomething(String param);

/**
 * Delegates to {@link #doSomething(String)} and thus ignores the second argument 
 * by default. Subclasses should override this method to return a better result,
 * taking the second argument into account
 */
public int doSomething(String param, String secondParam) {
    return doSomething(param);
}
```

Existing subclasses would still work, but would be in a "degraded" mode, where the second argument is always ignored.

New subclasses would simply be implemented the following way:

```
@Override
public int doSomething(String param) {
    doSomething(param, "theOptimalDefaultValue");
}

@Override
public int doSomething(String param, String secondParam) {
    // compute the result using the two arguments
}
```

Comment: Although this would work, I think it adds some confusion to the implementer. Deprecating the method, but still requiring it to be overridden.